# What does this MIPS assembly code correspond to?

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32, mars-simulator

I am learning MIPS assembly language. This is an exercise I am trying to understand. The question is:

**What does the following code correspond to?**

```
Name:   move    $t0,    $zero
Loop:   add     $t1,    $t0,    $t0
        add     $t1,    $t1,    $t1
        add     $t2,    $a0,    $t1
        sw      $zero,  0($t2)
        addi    $t0,    $t0,    1
        slt     $t3,    $t0,    $a1
        bne     $t3,    $zero,  Loop
        jr      $ra
```

I already know the meaning of each instruction, how the directives work and what a for loop is. When I try to run the code in MIPS Mars Simulator it ends with error, probably because values contained in the registers $a0 and $a1 are needed to begin with.

I don't get the bigger picture. What happens during each loop iteration? Is it just a part of a bigger algorithm? What is it supposed to do?

Comment: By the looks of it it just clears a chunk of memory (sets each element to 0).

Comment: @Michael Yeah, however why is it doubling `$t0` each time? That's what confuses me.

Comment: It's actually calculating `$t0 * 4` (because each element in the array is 4 bytes). But I have no idea why they did it with two additions instead of `sll $t1, $t0, 2`.

Comment: @m0skit0: it's just a convoluted way to move the target address 4 bytes on each iteration. `$t0` holds the index of the word array to be zeroed, then it "multiplies" it by 4 by issuing the two adds

Comment: @m0skit0 Does it mean that $a1 (supposedly y) number of memory addresses starting from the address contained in $a0 (supposedly addr(x) ) are set to 0 and then the loop ends?

Comment: Please check and improve my answer. Thank you.

Comment: @Michael For most CPUs, adding is faster than bit shifting if you're bit shifting by a small amount like 1 or 2. This isn't just a MIPS thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading the comments I guess the answer is somehow clearer.
At the beginning of the code, `$a0` and `$a1` should already have some value, let's suppose `x` and `y` respectively.

The first line `move $t0, $zero` would be `int i = 0;` in high level programming language, or the initial value of a `do-while (condition)` loop.

The following:

```
Loop: add $t1, $t0, $t0
      add $t1, $t1, $t1
```

is when the loop begins and would be like:

```
int j = 2 * i;
    j = 2 * j;
```

which shortly means `int j = 4 * i;` , the iterator is multiplied by 4 because MIPS registers are made of 32 bits, which means 4 bytes.

Then `add $t2, $a0, $t1` corresponds to `int k = x + j;` or in other words to `int k = x + 4 * i`.

The next instruction `sw $zero, 0($t2)` stores `0` into the memory whose address is offset by `0` from the address of the value contained in `$t2`.

`addi $t0, $t0, 1` increments `i++;` and

```
slt  $t3,  $t0,   $a1
bne  $t3,  $zero, Loop
jr   $ra
```

checks if `i < y` is satisfied, which is the condition of the `do - while (i < y)` loop. In case it is still true, the loop goes on setting to `0` the next element in memory, otherwise the loop ends returning to `$ra`.

Comment: Instead of `int k = x + j;`, I'd write either `uintptr_t` or `void *`.  I mean yes in asm everything is just an integer, but if you're using C terminology, you might as well keep track of which integers are addresses of valid memory and going to be dereferenced later.

Comment: It's not a `for`-loop.